# Adding values to an array when random numbers are generated

Tags: javascript

I would appreciate some help in getting a random number generator adding to an empty array.

Could you tell me how I would do this in javascript. I already have random numbers being output - random array of numbers - the array is then randomly selected and output the number. How would I make another array storing the values each time the randomise button is pressed ?

```
    // Suites

var suites= new Array();
suites[0] = "Hearts";
suites[1] = "Spades";
suites[2] = "Diamonds";
suites[3] = "Clubs";

    // Values

var values = new Array();
values[0] = "Ace";
values[1] = "King";
values[2] = "Queen";
values[3] = "Jack";
values[4] = "2";
values[5] = "3";
values[6] = "4";
values[7] = "5";
values[8] = "6";
values[9] = "7";
values[10] = "8";
values[11] = "9";
values[12] = "10";    

function myFunction()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("demo")
    var y=document.getElementById("demo2")
    x.innerHTML= values[Math.floor((Math.random())*12)]
    y.innerHTML= suites[Math.floor((Math.random())*4)]
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Eddybaby/RmtkF/

Comment: Please show some code...

Comment: So you're essentially asking how to add elements to an array in JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks for your replies.

here is my jsfiddle: I cannt find my random number generator. but this is ultimately what im trying to achieve -  I want the cardsdealt to be recorded in a new array 


thanks


http://jsfiddle.net/Eddybaby/RmtkF/

Comment: JavaScript tutorials should cover arrays thoroughly. Have a look at http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object.

Comment: do you want to add the generated deals to an array?

Comment: Yeah thats what im trying to do. Following a few ways others have done it on various fiddles I still cant manage to get the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a more clean OOP solution.
Use a `card` object constructor to store each card, so you can easily pass it around and store it in a array using push.

http://jsfiddle.net/WLuu4/

```
var dealistory = new Array(); //array that will hold all cards generated

//card constructor
function card(value, suite){ 
    return ({
        'value': value,
        'suite': suite
    });
}

//random card generator
function randomCard(){

    var suites = ["Hearts","Spades","Diamonds","Clubs"];
    var values = ["Ace","King","Queen","Jack","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"];

    var s = values[Math.floor((Math.random()) * 12)];
    var v = suites[Math.floor((Math.random()) * 4)];

    return card(s, v);
}

//deal button action
deal.onclick = function(){

    var newCard = randomCard();

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = newCard.value;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = newCard.suite;

    dealHistory.push(newCard); //add card to history array
    console.log(dealHistory);
}
```

dealHistory array example:
[image]

---

### Edit:

I added a function `printCard` to generate html for each card and a function `printHist` that traverse the history array calling `printCard` to display every item on screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/WLuu4/1/

[image]

```
//generate html for a card
function printCard(card){

    var cardHTML = '';
    cardHTML+='<div class="card">';
    cardHTML+='<div class="suite">'+card.suite+'</div>'
    cardHTML+='<div class="value">'+card.value+'</div>'
    cardHTML+='</div>';

    return cardHTML;
}

//generate html for each card in an array
function printHist(array){
    var html="";
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        html += printCard(array[i]);
    }
    return html;
}
```

Comment: Objects are fine, but strings are for people, not computers. Card rank and suit values should be numbers. Note there are 13 ranks, not 12, so you'll need to fix that. Finally, "suit" has no "e".

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I totally agree, but I just don't want to turn his code to obscure for him, but I should have recommended in using integers for both properties in the real application, and handle the human version in the `printCard` fn. Ops I just inherited the typo from his code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to update the array:

```
var storeArray = [];

function onButtonPress(newValue){
    //do other stuff here?
    storeArray.push(newValue);
}
```

Comment: here is my jsfiddle: I cannt find my random number generator. but this is ultimately what im trying to achieve -  I want the cardsdealt to be recorded in a new array 


thanks


http://jsfiddle.net/Eddybaby/RmtkF/

Comment: If I stored the values inside the onButtonPress and subsitute the correct parameter would that work ?